# iMac 2012 stuck when loading user profiles

Tags: ios, mac, imac, high-sierra, startup

I have a very nasty issue on my Mac (2012, High Sierra, SSD, and 20GB RAM).

In the beginning, I was having boot issues (the Apple logo was stuck), but now I can get to a point (using Safe Mode) where I can select my user account or the "Guest" account.

But none of the accounts load. After selecting my account and entering the password, a black screen appears, but nothing else except the mouse pointer. Sometimes the spinning wheel keeps spinning, and sometimes it suddenly halts.

It's responsive nonetheless to keystrokes (it only "beeps" and if I press the power button on the back a window appears asking me if I want to restart or stop.

Here's what I already did:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> multimple times
- Disconnected **every** external device
- In recovery mode, checked and repaired disk, no issues
- In recovery mode, I tried reinstalling the OS and it completed
- Deleted many `.kext` files and `.plist` files in many directories
  (LaunchDaemons, LaunchItems...)

It looks like the user profiles are either corrupt or the iMac cannot load the Desktop.

Looks like it gets stuck loading something, a driver, or whatever.
But I don't recall installing anything since the last power off (maybe just a couple of music plugins).

Comment: The first test would be to see if it boots to a clean OS on an external drive. If it won't boot to guest properly, then that suggests it's not a user account problem.

Comment: I have an old 2009 Macbook with Sierra installed, I could try using that disk image and change the boot sequence, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I can confirm that the external HD (taken form the old Macbook) boots perfectly fine

Comment: That rules out a hardware problem, so there's something wrong with the system disk. Can you create a brand new user account? Again, that would show where the problem lies. But, TBH, I'd wipe the disk, reinstall the OS and then migrate your data. (and then be careful about what you install.) With an old System, you need to make sure that any software is compatible with that 'vintage'.

Comment: I have used "First Aid" multiple times on the System disk, no issue found and the disk is OK. It's a 1TB SSD
Honestly I would like to have the Reinstall option as a last resort, I have lots of music softare and plugin and those will take days to reinstall...

Comment: First Aid is not going to solve a software problem. It's likely that something you've installed is the cause.